# What is the function of this "user user@domain anywhere" in an automated ftp script?

Tags: shell-script, ftp

I've come across the following line in a script (hostname has been changed)

```
open ftp-proxy.hostname.ac.uk
user adduser@admin.hostname.ac.uk  anywhere
```

Is the second line just logging in the user as adduser@admin.hostname.ac.uk or is it actually creating a new user? Also not sure what 'anywhere' refers to?

Is it the password or some other permission?

Answer (score 4):

From the ftp man:

**user user-name [password] [account]**

Identify yourself to the remote FTP server.  If the password is not specified and the server requires it, ftp will prompt the user for it (after disabling local echo).  If an account field is not specified, and the FTP server requires it, the user will be prompted for it. If an account field is specified, an account command will be relayed to the remote server after the login sequence is completed if the remote server did not require it for logging in.  Unless ftp is invoked with “auto-login” disabled, this process is done automatically on initial connection to the FTP server.